# Failed to deploy project - SSIS Error Number: 27203

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssis

I have created an SSIS project in Visual Studio 2019 containing multiple packages that upload Avro files to a AzureStorage connection type.

The project is targeting SQL2017, I have Azure Feature Pack installed on my machine version  2017 64bit.

This works ok on my machine but I am getting an error trying to deploy to SQL Server2017 to SSISDB Catalog:

> Failed to deploy project. For more information, query the operation_messages view for the operation identifier '10'. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)
>
> Server Name: Datastore1
> Error Number: 27203
> Severity: 16
> State: 1
> Procedure: SSISDB.catalog.deploy_project
> Line Number: 139

On the SQL server I did:

```
SELECT * FROM SSISDB.catalog.operation_messages
```

And could see this message:

> Failed to deploy the project. Fix the problems and try again later.:Unable to create the type with the name 'AzureStorage'.

Answer (score 1):

Installing Azure Feature Pack For SQL2017 has resolved my issue.